# Can't Chage Sibling Property on Input Focus

Tags: html, css

I want to change property of sibling element when input is focused, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.sibling {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

input:focus ~ .sibling {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="sibling"></div>
<input type="text">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it selects only the elements following it...

Comment: I hope this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53875661/10698741

Comment: I would like to know the reason of the reopen vote .. If I am wrong I would like to know how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your html order

```
<input type="text">
<div class="sibling"></div>
```